# Interpreting IE9 ltime & htime localStorage timestamps

Tags: internet-explorer-9, local-storage, timestamp, computer-forensics

Here is some sample XML from an IE9 localStorage file:

```
<root>
  <item name="1264474612:page_insights:latestversion" 
  value="6"
  ltime="1024039440" 
  htime="30244985" />
</root>
```

I am trying to figure out how to interpret these kinds of records, including the ltime and htime values. I've figured out from research that it has to do with IE9 localStorage and comes from `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\DOMStore\`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ltime` and `htime` is part of a 64-bit time value where one is the lower and the other is the higher 32-bit value.

Two most commonly used 64-bit time formats are 64-bit version of Unix (*POSIX*) time and Windows *FILETIME* (64-bit only).

- *POSIX* time is the number of seconds since January 1st 1970 in UTC.
- Windows *FILETIME* is the number of nano-seconds since January 1st 1601 in UTC.

Using both `ltime` and `htime`, to get the 64-bit value, each must be converted to hexadecimal first.

```
ltime = 1024039440 (decimal) = 0x3d099a10 (hexadecimal)
htime =   30244985 (decimal) = 0x01cd8079 (hexadecimal)

value = (htime x 0x100000000) + ltime
      = (0x01cd8079 x 0x100000000) + 0x3d099a10
      = 0x01cd807900000000 + 0x3d099a10
      = 0x01cd80793d099a10 (hexadecimal)
      = 129901222467050000 (decimal)
```

If the above result is calculated using *FILETIME* and *POSIX* format, the *FILETIME* time would be `2012-08-22, 08:17:26.705`, while *POSIX* time would be `4116407840-06-22, 09:53:20`. So, it's more likely that the *FILETIME* format is used for the timestamp since the *POSIX* time would go way past current year (2012).

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a program to decode these values for you, check out [DCode](https://www.digital-detective.net/digital-forensic-software/free-tools/).

[image: DCode]
<sub>(source: [digital-detective.co.uk](http://www.digital-detective.co.uk/images/screenshots/Dcode.png))</sub>

You would choose the value `Windows: Cookie Date (Lo Value, Hi Value)`, and enter the numbers like `1024039440,30244985`.

With UTC as the timezone, these values are interpreted as: `Wed, 22 August 2012 15:17:26 UTC`